# How to use DTO in services file of nestjs app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I want to fetch data of a particular person from mongodb on the basis of username and password values,but i got all the data of db instead of particular person which i passed in username and password.

Here is the code of DTO:

```js
import {IsString, IsInt,IsEmail,IsNotEmpty, IsNumberString} from 'class-validator';

export class LoginDto {
    @IsEmail()
    username: string;

    @IsNumberString()
    password: string;
}
```

Here is the code of Services:

```js
async loginsys(credentials: LoginDto): Promise<any> {
    const cred = await this.student.find({ credentials }).exec();
    return cred;
}
```

Here is the code of controller:

```js
@Post('login')
log(@Body('credentials') credentials: LoginDto): any {
    return this.crudservice.loginsys(credentials);
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the database result and your expected result please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get exactly one entity, you can use `findOne` instead of `find`:

```
return this.student.findOne(credentials)
```

---

`find` should work if you pass your query to `where`:

```
find({where: credentials})`
```

`exec()` is not necessary.

Comment: still not working,i got all the entries as my output.But i want only that particular data according to my username and password

Comment: That's weird, `findOne` returns one entity only. What does your schema/model look like?

Comment: findOne only return the very first value of the collection

Comment: You have to use `findOne(credentials)` instead, see my edit. The problem is that you are actually querying for the field `credentials`, because `{credentials}` is shorthand for `{credentials: credentials}`